# ImageLoader UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol)

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using `universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar` in my android application . I am loading images from my server. But it throws me exception. Following is the stack trace.

```
04-11 12:02:29.410: E/ImageLoader(10672): UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [ http://104.238.81.220:8080/locator_userimages/+91 98686 33929.jpg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
```

I know there are some predefined url format , which UIL supports.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples

**But UIL gets image for same person from my local server i.e**  `http://192.168.1.12:8080/locator_userimages/+91 98686 33929.jpg`

Below is code for setting up image loader instance.

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(this);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.member_icon)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.member_icon)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(50)).build();
        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();
        imageLoader.init(config);
```

for loading images i used this.

```
ivUserImage = (RoundedImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
imageLoader.displayImage(imagePath, ivUserImage, imageOptions);
```

**My question is that why UIL is getting same image from my local server but not from remote server ?**

Am i missing anything here ?

Plz help .

Answer (score 1):

I know you already figured this out but I have a error message infront of me and I can see that there is no space inside of the [], your problem was that there was a space at the beginning of the URL so you should have used the .trim() method

```
[ http://104.238.81.220:8080/locator_userimages/+91 98686 33929.jpg]
```

should have been

```
[http://104.238.81.220:8080/locator_userimages/+91 98686 33929.jpg]
```